# JSON API to HTML

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I try using different instructions to use a JSON API from a Wordpress-System in a HTML-Teamplate. Unfortunately I do not succeed. Does anyone have any idea how I can read the section "Content" of http://www.earnyour21.de/api/get_page/?id=1588?

```
blog: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.earnyour21.de/api/get_page/?id=1588',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to know how to access the content object within the `data` via JavaScript? If so will the structure of the json always be the same?

Comment: Yes, I think the structure of JSON always be the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data structure of the JSON will always be the same, you can simply access the object directly using the objects name in JS.

```
blog: function(){
 $.ajax({
url: 'http://www.earnyour21.de/api/get_page/?id=1588',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
  $('#content_test').append(data['page']['content']);
 },
 error: function(data){
  $('#content_test').append(data['page']['content']);
 }
});
}
```

Basically you need to use jquery to grab the div with an id of content_test and then append your data from the json. http://api.jquery.com/append/ and http://www.json.com/ for further reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I evaluate this in html? For example: <div id="content_test"></div>

Comment: So you would like to add the text within the JSON `content` object to a div so it would look like this: `<div id="content_test"><p>start<\/p></div>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what I need to do

Comment: you are the best. Thank you very very much! :-)
Still one question: Why gets JSON instead of </p> this: <\/p>

Comment: I did not add the `<p>` tags because they were already included in the JSON `content` object. If `content` only had the text you could add it like: $('#content_test').append('<p>'+data['page']['content']+'</p>');` however there are many different ways to do that.

Comment: Sorry I have one further question: If I put it in the HTML code: 

     <a href="index.html" class="active-item">
      <script type="text/javascript">blog: function(){
       $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.earnyour21.de/api/get_page/?id=1588',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
    console.log(data['page']['content']);
     },
     error: function(data){
     console.log(data['page']['content']);
     }
     });
      }
          </script>
                </a>
I see nothing. What I am doing wrong? Sorry, I am a beginner

Comment: Open the browser's console. Usually `F12` and look if there are any errors.

Comment: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name index.html:58
getPreventDefault() sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie stattdessen defaultPrevented.

Comment: You need to name your function, `function SOMENAME(){//ajax here}`. Make sure to call your function as well...

Comment: Okay the error is going away but I see nothing. It have to work also local, right?

Comment: Are you calling it in your javascript, ie: `SOMENAME();`? Check this tutorial out to help with the basics: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript